# Will XQuery work inside a SQL Server 2008 Stored Procedure

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, xquery, sql-server-profiler

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 - Version 10.0.6556.0

```
;WITH dataAsXml AS
(   
   SELECT
     xmlData.myElement.value('@myAttribute1', 'varchar(10)') AS 'myAttribute1',
     xmlData.myElement.value('@myAttribute2', 'char(5)') AS 'myAttribute2'       
   FROM 
     @input.nodes('/myRootElement/childElement') AS xmlData(myElement)
)
INSERT INTO myTable (myCol1, myCol2)
SELECT myAttribute1, myAttribute2 FROM dataAsXml
```

The above xQuery doesn't seem to work from within a stored procedure. The data is definitely there but nothing is inserted into myTable. It works from query window but if the same thing is put inside a stored procedure, nothing seems to happen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myRootElement>
  <childElement myAttribute1="Value1" myAttribute2="value2"/>
</myRootElement>
```

Comment: Are you logging any other event? That event will only log XQuery, nothing else. Side point: `(@myAttribute1)[1]` could be just `@myAttribute1` because attributes are guaranteed unique

Comment: Will XQuery even work inside SQL Server 2008 Stored Procedure ? It seems to work in a query outside but not from within a stored procedure.

Comment: Yes sure, why would a stored procedure make a difference. Please sure your *full* stored procedure definition, along with how you are calling it